# Why does the URL I'm trying to scrape with Requests and Beautiful Soup 4 return a TypeError?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I was following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/) on how to make a web scraping application with Python. Specifically, I'm trying to scrape search results from a shopping website I frequent. Issue is, when I plug in this website it returns an error!

The entire function so far is as follows:

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def simple_get(url):

    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                return None

    except RequestException as e:
        log_error('Error during requests to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None


def is_good_response(resp):

    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return (resp.status_code == 200
            and content_type is not None
            and content_type.find('html') > -1)


def log_error(e):
    print(e)
```

And to test it, I just have the lines

```
raw_html = simple_get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
print len(raw_html)
```

And it's successfully printing the length of every website I've put in, *except* the one that I'm building the application for! When I put in that url, I get the error

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

The URL that's giving me a headache is

```
https://www.mercari.com/search/?facets=2&itemStatuses=1&keyword=loungefly&length=30&sortBy=2
```

Comment: You will need to pass the query parameters using the params argument to `get`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a template that you can get more easily.
Please make your path to the location of the Chrome driver.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "/Users/your_account/Downloads/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

url = 'https://www.mercari.com/search/?facets=2&itemStatuses=1&keyword=loungefly&length=30&sortBy=2'
driver.get(url)

# driver.quit()
```